# Google Analytics API query Active user

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I want to query the number of Daily active user from Google analytics API, by the Event label.

In details:
I have 2 event Categories, each contain 2 Event label. like this:
(Category)    -> (Action)  -> (Label)

> ```
> 1. ui_category_A -> ui_action -> Click_button_A
> 2. ui_category_A -> ui_action -> Click_button_B
> 3. ui_category_B -> ui_action -> Click_button_A
> 4. ui_category_B -> ui_action -> Click_button_B
> ```

I want to query the Google analytics with API, to extract the number of daily active user, who have tracked the event with (1.) only.

How to do the query with parameters? 
Thanks!

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extract these data you should construct the API request with the library of your choice. Whichever you choose I will provide you with the parameters that will give you the results you want.

- **metrics:** ga:users
- **dimensions:** ga:eventCategory,ga:eventAction,ga:eventLabel
- **filters:** ga:eventCategory==ui_category_A;ga:eventAction==ui_action;ga:eventLabel== Click_button_A
- **start_date:** today
- **end_date:** today

If you just want the number of users you can skip the dimensions. Also be aware that the results will depend on the processing time of GA.

If you want real-time results you can look into the beta of real-time reporting [API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/reference/)

Comment: That Great!. I want to ask one more thing.
If I have queried 2 eventLabel, Click_button_A & Click_button_B,
I have used [filters: ga:eventCategory==ui_category_A;ga:eventAction==ui_action;ga:eventLabel=@Click_button, but I guess there is duplicate user on A and on B. How to calculate / query the sum of non duplicate user?

Comment: One thought would be to apply a segment on your query. Use Google Analytics to create a new segment based on Users that had exactly the Event Category, Action and Label of one event and not the other one. Then you can apply the segment Id on your API query(you would need to make two calls). The other one is to create a custom dimension based on the user's clientId so you would be able to discern true users on you Analytics. If the above answer is what resolved your first issue you can mark it as accepted.

Comment: Thanks your answer. I feel so confuse how to do that. Could you describe in more details or is there any other method?

Comment: One more thing, is it possible to query 30 days records in daily user. Without call this api by 30 times?